# h:selectOneMeny valueChangeListner is not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using h:selectOneMenu for dropdown but the valueChangeListner is not firing.
I can not use submit() onChange as it will refresh my entire page and i will lose the selected values for other components. Please suggest how to fire valueChangeListner without affecting other components on the page.

The h:selectOneMenu implemented like below:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="Q1List"
     value="#{myBean.q1Value}"                                                             onclick="showHideQ1()"//To open another field based on value selected, working fine
valueChangeListener="#{myBean.q1ValueChangeListner}">            
<f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Make a selection"/>              
<f:selectItems value="#{RateComparision.q1OptionsList}" id="dr1"/>                        
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Note: i can not use ajax or anything like that as my page is not supporting them.
Any JS solution or component property may help me.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: [mcve] please to replicatw

Comment: Hi, I have a alternate way, sharing the same here:  instead of valueChangeListner, i put one input hidden field and on selection called JS function and in the JS function i have assigned the selected value to the hidden field. Now in the bean, using request.getParameter("nameOf theHiddenField") i can able to get teh value.  But there is some issue, the h:selectOneMenu is not giving the updated value it is always passing the first item of the list.